# Handlebars doesn't render json

Tags: handlebars.js, handlebars.java

JSON it's pulling from:

```
unverifiedCompanies=[{"email":"testcompany@company.com","company_number":"09999999","company_name":"Name_123","full_name":"test","phone_number":"xyz"},{"email":"testtwo@company.com","company_number":"09999999","company_name":"Name_123","full_name":"test","phone_number":"xyz"}]
```

Iterating with

```
{{#each unverifiedCompanies}}
<tr>
  <td>{{this}}</td>
  <td>{{this.company_name}}</td>
  <td>{{this.full_name}}</td>
  <td>{{phone_number}}</td>
  <td>{{email}}</td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
```

However, only `{{this}}` displays `{"email":"testcompany@company.com","company_number":"09999999","company_name":"Name_123","full_name":"test","phone_number":"xyz"}` or `{"email":"testtwo@company.com","company_number":"09999999","company_name":"Name_123","full_name":"test","phone_number":"xyz"}` and all the others won't display.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your content with braces {} in order to have it in JSON format. I guess the problem you have is that unverifiedCompanies is not resolved.

```
{unverifiedCompanies=[{"email":"testcompany@company.com","company_number":"09999999","company_name":"Name_123","full_name":"test","phone_number":"xyz"},{"email":"testtwo@company.com","company_number":"09999999","company_name":"Name_123","full_name":"test","phone_number":"xyz"}]}
```